# jQuery search page for documents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissable">
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <div id="Section">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" id="SearchText" class="form-control link-search" placeholder="Document Name..." style="width:20%;margin-left: 43%;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="ButtonSearch" class="btn btn-default SearchButtons" style="float: right; margin-right: -2%;" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="reset" value="Clear Search" id="ButtonClearSearch" class="btn btn-default SearchButtons" style="margin-left: -69%;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 2%;">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#edoccollapse3">Panel One</a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div id="edoccollapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="my-ul">
                            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Test Document 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Test Document 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Test Document 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#edoccollapse2">Panel Two</a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div id="edoccollapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="my-ul">
                            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Test Document 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Test Document 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Test Document 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Test Document 7</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#SearchText").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13)
            search($(this).val());
    });

    $('#ButtonSearch').click(function() {
        search($("#SearchText").val());
    });

    function search(keyword) {
        var textboxValue = keyword.toLowerCase();
        $('.panel-body').each(function() {
            var exist = false;
            $(this).find('.my-ul li').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('a').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(textboxValue) !== -1) {
                    exist = true;
                }
            });
            if (exist === false) {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('in');
            } else {
                $(this).parent().addClass('in');
            }
        });
    }

    // When user wants to clear search

    $("#ButtonClearSearch").click(function() {
        $("#SearchText").val("");
        $('.panel-body').each(function() {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('in');
        });
        $('#SearchText').blur(function () {
            if ($.trim(this.value) == null) {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder','Document Search'));

            }
        });
    });
});
```

**My Goal**

I would like to display an alert if the user types in a word that doesn't match any document names, saying "No documents found that match **what the user typed in**".  Also, currently when a user doesn't type in anything and clicks search, every panel opens.  If the textbox is empty and the user tries to search.. I would like an alert to pop-up saying "No value to search".  I am lost on where to put this code because the jQuery is using `.each` and I don't need an alert for every item that it is searching.

**Example in Action**

[Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/pzApCVq9MA)

Comment: No value is simple... just add your alert and `return` before doing anything else

Comment: @charlietfl where do I put that?

Comment: inside button click...check for value before calling `search()`

Comment: @charlietfl omg.. I was looking too far into this haha

Comment: Okay, but what about the alert where what they typed in doesn't match any documents?

Comment: Depends if you want one for each panel or not. Not clear about that

Comment: @charlietfl no  need for each panel.  just in general

Comment: u can use `if( this.value == "" ) {
                        alert( "no items to search" );
                        return;
                        }`   inside your keyup event somthing like : `$("#SearchText").keyup(function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13){
              if( this.value == "" ) {
                        alert( "no items to search" );
                        return;
                        }                
search($(this).val());

          }
 });`

Comment: then use the filter idea in answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class to your documents, like `documents` and then loop through each of these documents, filter by one that the html contains the search terms and check for the length of the remaining array. Something like

```js
$('input').on('change', function(value) {
  var val = $('input').val();
 var array = $('.documents').filter(function(index, item) {
    return item.innerHTML.indexOf(val) !== -1;
  })
  if(array.length == 0) {
  alert("No documents found that match " + val);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <li class="documents">doc 1</li>
  <li class="documents">doc 2</li>

  <li class="documents">doc 3</li>

  <li class="documents">doc 4</li>

</div>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: suggest adding the hide/show to filtered elements also

Comment: Anyway you could incorporate this into my bootply that I have in the question?

Comment: @GTown-Coder I gave you a solution, I won't code it for you to just copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello please try following this : https://www.bootply.com/VSh5pyBz5E
I have used console.log instead of alert in above bootply. 
alert shown in below code.
Only change is in js code :

```
    $(function() {

    $("#SearchText").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13)
            search($(this).val());
    });

    $('#ButtonSearch').click(function() {
      let searchVal = $("#SearchText").val();
      if(!searchVal){
        alert("No value to search");
        return;
      }
      search(searchVal);
    });

    function search(keyword) {
        var textboxValue = keyword.toLowerCase();
        var exist = false;
        $('.panel-body').each(function() {
            $(this).find('.my-ul li').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('a').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(textboxValue) !== -1) {
                    exist = true;
                }
            });
            if (exist === false) {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('in');
            } else {
                $(this).parent().addClass('in');
            }
        });
      if(!exist){
        alert("No documents found that match what the user typed in");
      }
    }

    // When user wants to clear search

    $("#ButtonClearSearch").click(function() {
        $("#SearchText").val("");
        $('.panel-body').each(function() {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('in');
        });
        $('#SearchText').blur(function () {
            if ($.trim(this.value) == null) {
                $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder','Document Search'));

            }
        });
    });
});
```